# aligning components in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a following html code using bootstrap 3.0

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 300px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Ticket" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient" type="button">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
             </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group pull-left" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Tools
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group pull-right" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> New Ticket
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it looks now:

[image]

Exected:

[image]

How can I achieve expected result ?

Comment: I think you only need the `pull-left` div and `pull-right` div. Can you move the input and search icon button into the `pull-left` div? - that might fix your problem.

Comment: You migh tbe right! I'm going to try that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/7y1x3fun/)

You need to use the `display: inline;` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try using bootstrap's native .inline-form class.

Just wrap your html into a div with 'form-inline' class like this:

```
    <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 300px">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Ticket" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient" type="button">
                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                 </button>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group pull-left" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Tools
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group pull-right" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> New Ticket
            </button>
        </div>      
     </div>
    </form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnngmf1b/5/

See this link : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

PS: it only works for large screened devices >768px.